# Joomla 3.0 where are Component Params stored?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, components

My question is where are joomla 3.0 component parameters stored. I searched them in Database. I found out that module params are there but *component* params are not there. 
 Any ideas where they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are stored in #__menu table, column `Params`.

Answer (score 5):

For Joomla 3.4 you will find the component params or component options saved in the _extensions table.

Open the table, locate and open your component and look for the 'params' field.